# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is my code, which is so basic. But upon running I am getting,

> Error: Unable to initialize main class testPackage.myTestClass Caused
> by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

......

```
package testPackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class myTestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/reshmabibin/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://artoftesting.com/selenium-tutorial");
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("https://artoftesting.com/selenium-tutorial");
    

    }   }
```

I am not sure , If I have added the path correctly or not.
I am using mac.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't set classpath to your selenium jar download [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/download/selenium-4.4.0/selenium-server-4.4.0.jar)

And if you are a ubuntu user the below command will be used to set classpath

```
export CLASSPATH=:./selenium-server-4.4.0.jar
```

Compile and run it again.

for reference selenium dev [click this](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

**Hope it helps**